# what talks IMAP mail server? ↨♥☺

Tags: c#, email, imap

It Is logs of my application in debug mode:

Talking with imap.ya.ru : http://s013.radikal.ru/i325/1412/10/14b46c9d7a2c.png .

Talking with imap.gmail.com : http://s61.radikal.ru/i174/1412/d2/113d5fc6289f.png .

Whats means these symbols?

I use C#.

What I include:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Security;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

Fragments of my Code:

```
int port = useSSL ? portIMAPoverSSL : portIMAP;
Stream stream = new TcpClient(ImapServerName,port).GetStream();
stream.ReadTimeout = 10;
if (useSSL)
{
    SslStream ssl = new SslStream(stream);
    ssl.AuthenticateAsClient(ImapServerName);
    stream = ssl;
}
StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(stream,Encoding.ASCII);
w.AutoFlush = true;
StreamReader r = new StreamReader(stream,Encoding.ASCII);
```

to read Server messages and  not  blocking  GUI  I use this procedure:

```
static string readServerAndProcessMessages()
{
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                return r.ReadLine();
            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {
                Application.DoEvents();
            }
        }
}
```

And Sometimes this code:

```
string serv = readServerAndProcessMessages();
```

, returns  (without <>) :  <↨♥☺>, and sometimes <↨♥☺ 0>    as prefix of server responses. What this means??  IMAP4 RFC was readed, any info about this  I not found.

Comment: What is the client software?

Comment: my own application, written in C#

Comment: Do you assign proper tags for issued commands? Which part of your code prints these symbols? It looks like some variable was not initialized, if only you did not program your client in such a way that it denotes some features/states with these symbols.

Comment: Proper tags? something like A001, A002 ? But any tags accepts, at least on these servers.    I print exact messages to server, and messages from server  with additional whitespace only. I am not use such symbols, they appears randomly.

Comment: Could it be a bug in buffering in your code?

Comment: This looks very much like a client bug.

Comment: Please, add all relevant code to the question itself and use proper formatting.

Comment: fragments of code was added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Source of ERROR was found!!!

Due to:

```
stream.ReadTimeout = 10;
```

, SSL protocol little cracks, and appears  ↨♥☺  artifact!!!

With using Async read operation this BUG disappears!!! I am happy.